# Getting ByteArray from TCP Header in pypcapfile

Tags: python, tcp, pcap

I want to parse TCP Packets individually without using PCAPLib's own data structures. For that reason, I need to get the bytearray of TCP header.

```
from pcapfile import savefile

capfile = open('delta_capture.pcap')
sf = savefile.load_savefile(capfile)

for packet in sf.packets:
    print packet.timestamp
    print packet.packet
    print packet.header # Returns a library object, I need the bytearray instead, as I want to use my own data structure and parse.

capfile.close()
```

I tried debugging and inspectiong the object structure, but couldn't see any objects which store the actual bytes in the TCP header.

Screenshot for debugger result for the variable "packet":

[image: Screenshot for debugger result for the variable "packet"]

Is it even possible to do so in this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `bytearray` of the header is not directly accessible.  Various fields in the header are parsed, and the entire packet is available:

```
for packet in sf.packets:
    print(packet.timestamp)
    print(packet.packet)

    # show header fields
    print(packet.header.contents.magic)          # file magic number
    print(packet.header.contents.major)          # major version number
    print(packet.header.contents.minor)          # minor version number
    print(packet.header.contents.tz_off)         # timezone offset
    print(packet.header.contents.ts_acc)         # timestamp accuracy
    print(packet.header.contents.snaplen)        # snapshot length
    print(packet.header.contents.ll_type)        # link layer header type
    print(packet.header.contents.byteorder)      # byte order specifier
    print(packet.header.contents.ns_resolution)  # nanosecond resolution

    # show entire packet
    print(packet.raw())
```